# Bootstrap container on top of navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just started to play around with Bootstrap and I'm following the dashboard example. I'm running into the container being on top of the `navbar` and the 1st link ends up getting clipped. How can I fix this?

Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand">Dashboard</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-sidebar">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#"> link # 1 </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#"> link # 2 </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use a **margin-top** on the container div like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 50px;">
```

or you can just set this into your css file: `body { padding-top: 50px; }`

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru/eyAVL/) the example.

Comment: I thought bootstrap would take care of this. I still cannot explain how it works on their example. I looked to the css and for those things there is nothing custom

Comment: Witch example? I can check it out and tell you how they did it. If you provide me an url. But i don't see any problem with the margin solution. If an element has position fixed, its very normal that the other elements are under it, so you handle this with a margin or a padding top.

Comment: If you speak about bootstrap oficial page, their header has a diferent class than your header. They use navbar-static-top witch means it's not fixed, if you scroll the page down you won't see the header anymore. But in your example, you ues navbar-fixed-top witch is another thing. If you replace their class with your using inspect element, they will have the same thing as you, content cut.

Comment: The dashboard example

Comment: On this example, they use padding-top: 50px; on body. Just check it out. It's the same thing. So in their css file (dashboard.css) you can find on the first line this : body {padding-top: 50px;} . Hope this helps, and understand that this is the solution for this case.